# What's the way to use MvvmCross Tibet binding?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, android-databinding

[The documentation of MvvmCross](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding) refers to `Tibet` binding, which allows to do the following binding expressions:

```
 Text FirstName + ' ' + LastName
```

and also

```
 If(test, if_true, if_false)
```

as some other similar examples.

However, there is no particular details on if it's currently available out of the box, or it needs some plugins, or it's still in development.

So, what's the status of that functionality? Also, can I use it (if it's still available these days) for defining something like this:

```
local:MvxBind="Text User.FirstName + ' ' + User.LastName" 
local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(If(GreaterThan(Users.Count, 0), false, true))"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is getting more and more support with each release.

You can see the [unit tests in the MvvmCross repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/Binding/Test/Parse/Binding/Swiss/MvxTibetBindingTest.cs) that test the implemented features of Tibet binding.

Also check the [`MvxTibetBindingParser` source code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/Parse/Binding/Tibet/MvxTibetBindingParser.cs) to see the operators that you can use and that the framework is able to recognize.